# как вставлять картинки в базу данных на php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, openserver

[image: отображение на сайте , в phpmyadmin][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agg0S.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eplle.jpg)

не могу вставить картинки в базу данных, тип файла в бд указала longblob. все остальные столбы работают на сайте, но когда ввожу в код <img src="img/" " alt=''> , появляются ромбики. Еще у меня вопрос, когда отдавать сайт заказчику, он сможет вставлять картинки в базу данных?

Comment: Обычно картинки лучше хранить не в базе, а в файлах

Comment: Обычно вставляют не файлы, а путь до них или имена, а сами файлы где-то в другом месте сохраняют. Именно файлы вряд ли удастся вам корректно вставлять. Можно попробовать вставить файл в бинарном виде, предварительно приведя к нему. Почитайте про [Бинарные типы данных](https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/2.3.php). Чтобы ответить как-то более конкретно, задайте более конкретный вопрос